# What is the letter before or after a table name in a select/from statement in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT e.BusinessEntityID,e.HireDate,e.JobTitle
FROM [HumanResources].[Employee] e
```

What does e. stand for in select statement?
What does e stand for in from statement?

```
USE [AdventureWORks2012]
SELECT *
FROM [Person].[Person] p
```

What does p stand for in from statement?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The letter e is alias for table [HumanResources].[Employee]  see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx for details.

Answer (score 2):

It is [table alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

It is being used as shorthand for table name to improve readability of code.

Also it is useful when you're performing self-joins (joins of table to itself) in order to access exact fields from one joined table or another.